# Attempting to Installing Software(deb)

Tags: pi-4, software-installation, raspberry-pi-os, 64-bit

Update: I found that I couldn't find a arm64 for chrome remote desktop. Thanks Ccode!

I am having issues based on installing deb files on the raspberry pi os. I get errors when I attempt to install something. For example: I attempted to install Chrome Remote Desktop, but it ask to install soo much apps that I can't install on the raspberry pi. I tried installing the things it wants, and apt suggested that I should use a command to repair the app. I did it, but it says it can't install everything else. I expected that It will install all of it, but it didn't. My Dad has told me that the raspberry pi may not be meant to install these, but I was wondering if maybe there is some way to bypass these errors?

Thanks!

Using Raspberry pi 4 with raspberry pi os

UPDATE INFO:

I tried to update the architecture, but did not work. There is specific parts of the app that I can't download.

Here is the command log:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ sudo dpkg -i chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 92141 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 (99.0.4844.11) over (99.0.4844.11) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of chrome-remote-desktop:amd64:
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on xbase-clients.
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on python3 (>= 3.5).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on python3-psutil.
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.17).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libexpat1 (>= 2.0.1).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.9.10).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libnspr4 (>= 2:4.9-2~).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libnss3 (>= 2:3.22).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libx11-6.
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libxcb1 (>= 1.9.2).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libxext6.
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libxfixes3.
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libxrandr2.
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libxtst6.

dpkg: error processing package chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.69) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ sudo apt install xbase-clients
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 : Depends: xbase-clients:amd64 but it is not installable
                               Depends: python3:amd64 (>= 3.5) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: python3-psutil:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libcairo2:amd64 (>= 1.2.4) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libdbus-1-3:amd64 (>= 1.9.14) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libexpat1:amd64 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libgbm1:amd64 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libgcc1:amd64 (>= 1:3.0)
                               Depends: libglib2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.31.8) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libgtk-3-0:amd64 (>= 3.9.10) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libnspr4:amd64 (>= 2:4.9-2~) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libnss3:amd64 (>= 2:3.22) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libpam0g:amd64 (>= 0.99.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libpango-1.0-0:amd64 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libx11-6:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libxcb1:amd64 (>= 1.9.2) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libxdamage1:amd64 (>= 1:1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libxext6:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libxfixes3:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libxrandr2:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libxtst6:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
 xbase-clients : Depends: x11-apps but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: x11-session-utils but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: x11-utils
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfuse2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  chrome-remote-desktop:amd64
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 48.7 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfuse2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  chrome-remote-desktop:amd64
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 48.7 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads $ sudo dpkg -i chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 92141 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 (99.0.4844.11) over (99.0.4844.11) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of chrome-remote-desktop:amd64:
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on xbase-clients.
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on python3 (>= 3.5).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on python3-psutil.
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.17).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libexpat1 (>= 2.0.1).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.9.10).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libnspr4 (>= 2:4.9-2~).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libnss3 (>= 2:3.22).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libx11-6.
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libxcb1 (>= 1.9.2).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1).
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libxext6.
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libxfixes3.
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libxrandr2.
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 depends on libxtst6.

dpkg: error processing package chrome-remote-desktop:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.69) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 chrome-remote-desktop:amd64
```

Comment: Are you sure you're installing the debs for the correct architecture (arm, not amd / x86)

Comment: It says that I don't have the right architecture, and then I change it. still doesn't work. Note that more things needed to get installed in order for the app to be fully working.

Comment: What do you change? Find a deb with the correct architecture? Please an example to your query with full commands and output (error messages)

Comment: I did the command: sudo dpkg --add-architecture [architecture I need to have for deb file]

Comment: Pls re-read my previous comment... add full commands and msgs to your question. Your last command is of very limited value.. BTW: changing architecture on your Pi will not e.g. make an intel deb work on a Pi...

Comment: My apologies for not understanding. I have updated the post so that it contains my whole log.

Comment: 'amd64' - there's your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like your installing for the wrong arch.  Try downloading the file for armvl7 or arm and running again.

Comment: I don't see where you see that I didn't install the right one. it wants amd64, and I did that.

Comment: ` it wants amd64` Don't think so. You added amd64 so that's what it tries to install, As stated above it's the wrong (incompatible) architecture

Comment: @Friendlygabe777 Raspberry pi is arm not amd.  Your can't run a intel app on an arm computer.

Comment: Did not work. said the architecture did not exist.

Comment: On what? The pi or the website you were getting it off of?

Comment: The website. I don't see an architecture for arm64 on chrome remote desktop site. I saw that I wasn't able to do it. Thank you!